# How to access youtube json date from the youtube google api?

Tags: php, json, youtube

How can I access thing like the url to a banner image, the channel title, the subscriber count, and the default logo image url from youtube google's api's for Youtube?

An   [example of the JSON api can be found here](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,brandingSettings&id=UCyoUx3RguJRgbaMo07yc_KA&key=AIzaSyCZonTWlCv92Nd93j5CuFFcqGciLIe5rx4).

How can I access this contents using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

proceed in this way:

```
$youtube = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,brandingSettings&id=UCyoUx3RguJRgbaMo07yc_KA&key=AIzaSyCZonTWlCv92Nd93j5CuFFcqGciLIe5rx4");

$data = json_decode($youtube,true);

echo "BANNER IMAGE URL: ".$data['items'][0]['brandingSettings']['image']['bannerImageUrl']."<br>";
echo "CHANNEL TITLE: ".$data['items'][0]['brandingSettings']['channel']['title']."<br>";
```

and so on....

[this tools](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) its very good to view the structure of a json and extract what you need

Comment: please one question tell me how can i add in snippet> thumbnail>default>url

Comment: in the same way.... ['items'][0]['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url']...... try to understand what i ve done in the answer so you can find the element you need by yourself

Comment: Very nice for me please one last question this link include statistics how to i access subscriber count from statistics, https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,brandingSettings,statistics&id=UCyoUx3RguJRgbaMo07yc_KA&key=AIzaSyCZonTWlCv92Nd93j5CuFFcqGciLIe5rx4

Comment: oh thanks i got it my problem is solved bunddle of thanks

Answer (score 1):

This simple snippet should do the trick.

```
$myData = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,brandingSettings&id=UCyoUx3RguJRgbaMo07yc_KA&key=AIzaSyCZonTWlCv92Nd93j5CuFFcqGciLIe5rx4"));
var_dump($myData);
```

I would really recommend using cURL instead of file_get_contents() for performance reasons, however that should get you started.

Comment: how can i access bannerimage url and thumbnail default url